# Show fill animation in imageView while loading the image from server android

Tags: android, android-animation

[2 images of same icon with different color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xPhe.png)

We have to achieve the loading effect like the image attached below.

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHcdJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4065)  might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks this library save my time

Answer (score 0):

You can find the project code here [Source code](https://jumpshare.com/v/xF5Or6JbOSblgDPHASfc)

1. Change the image src in xml
2. Change the second image in MainActivity.
   Thanks